# Trailhead Apex Unit Testing

Tags: apex, unit-test, trailhead

I am doing Apex Unit Testing and in the Challenge, this is my code. I have this error of module not visible. Please help

```
 @isTest
private class VerifyDateTest{
    @isTest static void CheckDatesTest1(){
    Date Date1 = VerifyDate.CheckDates(System.today(),System.today()+1);
    Date Date2 = VerifyDate.CheckDates(System.today(),System.today()+15);
    System.assertequals(System.today(),System.today()+15, Date2);
    }

    @isTest static void CheckDatesTest2(){
    Date Date1 = VerifyDate.CheckDates(System.today(),System.today()+1);
    Date Date2 = VerifyDate.CheckDates(System.today(),System.today()+60);
    Integer Lastday = 30;
    System.assertequals(30, Lastday);
    }

    @isTest static void DateWithin30DaysTest1(){
    Date Date1 = VerifyDate.DateWithin30Days(System.today(),System.today()+2);
    Date Date2 = VerifyDate.DateWithin30Days(System.today(),System.today()+1);
    String Date3 = 'False';
    System.assertequals('False', Date3);
    }

    @isTest static void DateWithin30DaysTest2(){
    Date Date1 = VerifyDate.DateWithin30Days(System.today(),System.today()+1);
    Date Date2 = VerifyDate.DateWithin30Days(System.today(),System.today()+31);
    System.assertequals('False', Date2);
    }

    @isTest static void DateWithin30DaysTest3(){
    Date Date1 = VerifyDate.DateWithin30Days(System.today(),System.today()+1);
    Date Date2 = VerifyDate.DateWithin30Days(System.today(),System.today()+2);
    System.assertequals('True', Date2);
    } 

    @isTest static void SetEndOfMonthDateTest1(){
    Date Date1 = VerifyDate.SetEndOfMonthDate(System.today(),System.today()+1);
    integer Last = 30;
    System.assertequals(30, Last);
    } 

}
```

Comment: Is it an error, or is "Check This Challenge" telling you that you have not done something correctly? Do you have the exact text of the error?

Comment: FYI, regarding providing code examples: http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/responding-to-trailhead-challenge-questions

Comment: @Peter- it is an error. btw, Im asking about what is the meaning of my error module not visible and what caused that error and Im not asking for the actual answer for the trailhead.  Read

Comment: Not to worry...but you didn't post the error. The actual text of the error and where/when you are seeing it is all key information to answer your question. Otherwise we are guessing. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer but this never seemed to get something definitive. I'd suggest that the error here is caused by the test class being declared `private` - given that it's being invoked externally I think changing it to `public` would sort things out.

```
public class VerifyDateTest{
```

Comment: Ha, yeah, that's kind of obvious looking at it again. Good catch.

Answer (score 4):

If the `dateWithin30Days` method returns boolean, then a couple of your asserts will never work.

For instance the following:

```
Date Date2 = VerifyDate.DateWithin30Days(System.today(),System.today()+2);
System.assertequals('True', Date2);
```

First of all, `Date2` is a Date data type.

But `'True'` is a String. So if you pass those two to `assertEquals` you will fail, as two variables of different data types can never be equal.

There is another instance where you are trying to assert, that looks like this:

```
System.assertequals(System.today(),System.today()+15, Date2);
```

Here this assert will also always fail. You are comparing the current date to the current date *plus 15*.

I think maybe you may need some basic help with understanding variables, data types, and using them.

In addition to the Trailhead module, you might benefit from checking out [Chapter 3 on sfdc99](http://www.sfdc99.com/beginner-tutorials/), which addresses some of these basics. I would also read the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assertEquals) on using `System.assertEquals`

**Note:** as a rule, this community [has decided](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/responding-to-trailhead-challenge-questions) that we will not provide specific code examples to answer Trailhead challenges.

Answer (score 1):

Well i can figure out a lot number of errors to your code!

So here we go.

1. This will never work as `System.assertEquals(expected,actual)` accepts only 2 parameters and the third parameter if at all there can only be a comment:

   ```
   System.assertequals(System.today(),System.today()+15, Date2);
   ```

   instead of what you wrote it should be like:

   ```
   System.assertequals(System.today()+15,Date2);
   ```
2. Here you are trying to compare a string with a boolean value because the return type of method is boolean and anything you write in ' ' becomes a string

   ```
   System.assertequals('False', Date2);
   ```

   Instead you should write:

   ```
   System.assertequals(False, Date2);
   ```

Also, I would mention there is mistake of return type in whole block of this function.i can help you with the correct block of code:

so instead of this which is wrong:

```
 @isTest static void DateWithin30DaysTest1(){
    Date Date1 = VerifyDate.DateWithin30Days(System.today(),System.today()+2);
    Date Date2 = VerifyDate.DateWithin30Days(System.today(),System.today()+1);
    String Date3 = 'False';
    System.assertequals('False', Date3);
    }
```

try this:

```
@isTest static void DateWithin30DaysTest1(){
    Boolean Date1 = VerifyDate.DateWithin30Days(System.today()+2,System.today()+1);
    System.assertequals(False, Date1);
    }
```

this will surely work!

Comment: Your assertion message can be of any type. Point 1 is flat out wrong in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you over did this a little bit; you can make this much more simple.

Here is my code for this trailhead:

```
@isTest private class TestVerifyDate {
    @isTest private static void testWithinThirtyDays(){
        Date tomorrow = Date.today().addDays(1);
        Date result = VerifyDate.CheckDates(Date.today(),tomorrow);
        system.assertEquals(tomorrow, result);
    }  

    @isTest private static void testNotWithinThirtyDays(){
        Date nextMonth = Date.today().addDays(31);
        Date result = VerifyDate.CheckDates(Date.today(),nextMonth);
        system.assertNotEquals(nextMonth, result);
    }  
}
```